# Use predicted values with or without random part to plot Residuals with binnedplot of a logistic regression in glmer (lme4 package) in R?

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, residuals, lme4-nlme

Which binnedplot of the glmer should I use to check the model? The residuals against the predicted values without random part(REform=NA) or residuals against the predicted values with random part(REform=NULL)?

I have one binary response variable (y.10) derived from one continuous variable with around 50 to 75% of zeros. I want to model the probability to exceed the limit of 10.
For this example I used only one predictor "fragments" which is transformed by  taking the logarithm to get a normal distribution an later a better fit  . All variables are measured in tree regions (region). Within this regions are different plots (plot) and a set of samples were taken from some objects (object).

To inspect the residuals I used binnedplot like discribed in the answer of the question:
[Unexpected residuals plot of mixed linear model using lmer (lme4 package) in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63566/unexpected-residuals-plot-of-mixed-linear-model-using-lmer-lme4-package-in-r).
To save calculation time with very complex models I modeled at first with 
glm {stats} and based on this results the model with less variables with glmer{lme4}. Doing this I could observe a big difference in the binnedplot of residuals.

To examination the differences I created this example with only one variable. Like you can see in the picture bellow the models of glm and glmer without the random part show a very similar behavior. At the end the random part is not for interest. I need the random part only during model selection.

Which binnedplot of the glmer should I use to check the model? The residuals against the predicted values without random part(REform=NA) or residuals against the predicted values with random part(REform=NULL)?

The code and the resulting picture is given here:

```
fit.glm=glm(y.10 ~ x.t , data=data, family="binomial")
fit.glmer=glmer(y.10 ~ x.t + (1|region) + (1|plot) + (1|object), 
          data=data, family="binomial")

y.glm=predict(fit.glm, type ="response")
y.glmer=predict(fit.glmer,REform=NA,type ="response") 
y.glmer.ran=predict(fit.glmer,REform=NULL,type ="response")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(y.10~x, data=data, type="n", main="Models")
points(y.glmer.ran~data$x, col="green", pch=4, cex=0.5)
lines(y.glm~data$x, col="red")
lines(y.glmer~data$x, col="darkgreen")

binnedplot(fitted(fit.glm),resid(fit.glm), main="Binned residual plot glm")
binnedplot(y.glmer.ran,resid(fit.glmer), main="Binned residual plot glmer(REform=NULL)")
binnedplot(y.glmer,resid(fit.glmer), main="Binned residual plot glmer(REform=NA)")
```

[image: Shows in the first first Plot the glm fitted model (red) and glmer fitted models with (green crosses) and without (dark green line) random part. The other plots show the corresponding residuals.]

Answer (score 2):

You should use resid(fit.glmer,type="response") since default type is "deviance" while type of y.glmer is "response". I bet this will change pretty much your binnedplot figure of residuals against the predicted values with random part.
See also: [Interpreting a binned residual plot in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99274/interpreting-a-binned-residual-plot-in-logistic-regression)